# iframe a webpage in Facebook page

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

Recently Facebook allows adding iframe tabs to their pages. Static HTML pages can be added using a number of apps such as static HTML tab1, static HTML tab2, etc etc.. These apps allows to create a page in their editor window and adds a page tab. Since iframe can hold any website, I would like to add a custom web page, say stackoverflow.com or google.com to my page, so that they can be accessed from my page (or visible), using iframe. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [iframe apps](http://facebook.com/iframe.apps) to embed a website into a tab in your fanpage.
The app is https ready.